# How to automate flutter web UI application?

Tags: flutter, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to automate a flutter application which is running in Chrome browser using Selenium Web driver but couldn't find any locator (name, ID).

Below is the sample application to automate. We just need to click on left side menu.
https://flutter.github.io/samples/web/web_dashboard/#/

Please help me to find out the right solution to automate this type of applications.

Comment: I found out there is no way to get html elements of flutter applications and we can consider these apps as pictures rendered on canvas. And to Automate these type of applications Image-based Automation is the best approach. Read the article below to get an idea of Image-based automation: https://medium.com/@jkgupta0003/automated-testing-of-flutter-web-application-bcf781decd84

Comment: Please check whether this is helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564522/automate-flutter-web-application-using-selenium-webdriver